# Do I need to set send_page_view to false in my Google Tag in GTM if I have Enhanced Measurement turned on in GA4?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

By default when you add a Google Tag (GA4) in Google Tag Manager the `send_page_view` parameter is set to `true`. In GA4, when you enable "Enhanced Measurement" the "Page View" toggle is on and cannot be disabled.

Does the `send_page_view` parameter need to be set to `false` in the Google Tag settings in GTM in this case?

I tried debug mode and could not see a double page_view event, but this doesn't clarify what the proper setup should be.

Comment: It's okay, no need to change anything. The only way to send a pageview is via the send_page_view parameter in Google Tag. By disabling it, you won't be able to see any pageviews.

Comment: Thank you. That fits with what I am seeing. So what exactly is the "Page view" for the "Enhanced Measurement" doing which is on and can't be disabled? If you write the comment above as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's okay, no need to change anything. The only way to send a pageview is via the send_page_view parameter in Google Tag. By disabling it, you won't be able to see any pageviews.
The Enhanced Measurement feature includes the Pageview setting, which allows you to change the page counting method for server-side rendering pages or SPAs. You can find this setting under the Advanced tab.